# How to scale aiogram-based Telegram bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, horizontal-scaling

I wander what is the way to horizontal-scale telegram bot written using [aiogram](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram) framework? Tried to google on a subject of scaling telegram bots, but didn't find useful information.

With RESTful services it is possible to run multiple copies of the same service, but bot isn't RESTful. If I would run a Redis cluster which would be configured as a [Redis storage](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/fsm.html?highlight=storage#redis-storage) for the bots would I be able to run multiple instances of my bot and have a sane interaction with users?

Comment: Seems that it is impossible to run more than one bot instance. This exeption is raised when trying to launch the second bot with the same token: `aiogram.utils.exceptions.TerminatedByOtherGetUpdates: Terminated by other getupdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running`